# Change selected index of DropDownList into first index while change the checkbox into unchecked mode

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

In my ASP.NET MVC project I have a checkbox and when I check it then a DropDownList will be appeared and it is possible that I select an item from this DropDownList(I mean an item except first item in combo box) but when I uncheck the checkbox then the selected item of the DropDownList must be first index(I mean  - شغل را انتخاب نمایید -):

[image]

My checkbox(toggle button) is as below:

```
<div style="margin-top: 30px;margin-right: 8px" class="row col-md-7">
  <p>آیا شاغل هستید؟</p><label style="margin-top: -7px;margin-right: 20px" class="switch">
     <input class="switch-input" type="checkbox"  value="true" name="JobStatus"/>
     <span class="switch-label" data-on="هستم" data-off="نیستم"></span> <span class="switch-handle"></span>
     </label>
</div>
```

My dropdown is as below:

```
<div class="col-md-7" hidden="hidden" id="divJobsId" style="margin-top: 30px" tooltip="شغل" flow="down">
   @Html.DropDownList("JobsId", null, "- شغل را انتخاب نمایید -", htmlAttributes: new { type = "Text", @class = "form-control" })
   @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.JobsId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
</div>
```

I have done as below with jquery until now:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.switch-input').change(function () {
            debugger;
            if (this.checked) {
                $("#divJobsId").prop('hidden', false);
            } else {
                $("#divJobsId").prop('hidden', true);
                $("#JobsId").prop('show', false);
            }
            if ($("#divJobsId").is(':visible')) {
                $("#JobsId").chosen();
            }
        });
    });
```

How can I solve this problem? Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: You won't clear selection based on check or unchecked checkbox?

Comment: Hello, what do you mean? You mean it is not possible to return DropDownList selected item into first item("- شغل را انتخاب نمایید -") after unchecking the checkbox? If there is no way then I will encounter big problems.

Comment: You want selected data in drop-down list which once you have selected already?

Comment: No, Imagine when I checked the checkbox(when I checked the checkbox then I want to say I have a job and when the checkbox is unchecked then I have no job) and the DropDownList gets appeared and I choose for example the "کارگر" from the dropdown but again I uncheck the checkbox and the DropDownList gets hidden and at this time the selected item of the DropDownList must be first item("- شغل را انتخاب نمایید -")

Comment: When the checkbox is unchecked then no job in DropDownList must be chosen

Comment: Hi Mostafa, does your field have a default value (matching the first item in the checkbox)?

Comment: Hi Michael, I am not sure that I understood what you mean but I have edited my question and added (value="true") ( name="JobStatus") to my check box(toggle button)